# Is it good or bad to store the DB connection details with define()?

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, zend-framework, constants

Is it good or bad to store the DB connection details with define()?

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASS', 'xxx' );
define( 'DB_NAME', 'xxx' );
```

or better in an array below?

```
$config['db'] = array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => '3306',
    'user'     => 'someuser',
    'password' => 'SuperSecretPassword',
    'name'     => 'db_name',
);
```

I notice that popular frameworks such as Zend or Symfony don't use define for this configuration.

CodeIgniter,

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
...
```

What are the **benefits** of storing it in an array instead of `define()`? I notice that Zend appears **does not** use `define()` at all (I might be wrong as I am new to Zend). **Is it bad** to store somme **global contants** then in general?

In my limited knowledge, I do find storing some global contants useful, for instance, I can store my document root in this below then I can access it from everywhere - by just using `WEBSITE_DOCROOT`

```
define ( 'WEBSITE_DOCROOT', str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/' );
```

Unlike this method below that I have to use `dirname(__FILE__)` everytime,

```
// Load config file
$configFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../share/config/default.php';
```

which I could just use `WEBSITE_DOCROOT . '/../share/config/default.php';` to call the file. Isn't it easier and consistent?

Comment: `define` creates a constant. Constants cannot have their values changed. Variables can have their values changed at any time. By this definition, the advantage of a constant is that you know it can't be screwed up once it's set - it's always what it is initially. With variables, you get to alter them at any point in time. However, you cannot iterate constants like you can over arrays. When people aren't dumb and know what they're doing, they can use both. There is no huge advantage of one over another, it boils down to what you consider easier and cleaner to work with.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) this way you can rest assure your credentials are fairly protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitation to use `define`  instead of `array`. 
Frameworks use `arrays` for database connections functions because they want to have some `optional` parameters like `encoding`. another reason is there is no needs to `define` these consts and save memory for them while you just need them once(at bootstrap.php). the idea of `define` is accessing const everywhere, but for database configurations you don't need it.

*it is better to store database configurations in a file with `read-only` and `not executable` permission for `apache` and deny all access for other users. so this file could not be a php file. you can use `xml`, `ini` or other standard formats

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I ask - how can I configure `a file with read-only and not executable permission for apache and deny all access from other users`?

Comment: you should set apache as owner and permission to 600. you can do it with terminal or your cpanel.
in terminal run these two commands
`chown apache:apache /path/to/the/config/file`
`chmod 400 /path/to/the/config/file`

if you don't have access to terminal, go to cpanel->file manager and change directory to configs file and change it's permission

Comment: you're welcome. no you can't change permission with php, permissions should grant/deny by OS.

Answer (score 1):

- Using constants through out your application could be great for storing information like base-url, I cant really see any reason not to use them, that's their purpose.
- Using an Array instead is a matter of preference and design (architecture), the reason most frameworks are using arrays is that it's simply more convenient to store data using arrays (obviously)
- It is not bad at all to use a Global constant, if you find it useful to you then by all means use it to your benefit, I can imagine that in time, you'll understand why others prefer the array method.

However, for keeping your credentials safe I suggest to use [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)
I think it's probably the best way to do that.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I feel better using constants now. definite will look into `dotenv`. thank you.

Comment: `dotenv` is written in Ruby. How can we use Ruby in PHP?

Comment: sorry, my bad, here is the PHP version: [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: just have a quick look but not sure how to use it though - it lacks of solid example... for instance how can I store my db details above with `dotenv` and how can I access what i have stored?

Comment: did you read the documentation? it's really straight forward.. I suggest you to download it using composer and see the example file that you are getting with this package. I'm sure you'll figure this out.

Comment: I have read the doc. but for `Dotenv::required(array('DB_HOST', 'DB_NAME', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS'));` where am I going to get DB_HOST, etc from? and what can I do with `Dotenv::required(array('...'));`?

Comment: it's taken form the .env file

Answer (score 1):

Configurations and parameters  must be set outside of your PHP project
You have to keep in mind that this kind of work can be managed by a person that is not a developer, knowing nothing about PHP programming 
Use something standard for this : like XML, properties or conf files